# Google Sheets Apps Scripts how to populate specific text in the same row of the last non-empty cell in another specified column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm relatively new to Apps Scripts and am still refreshing my basic Java coding and Sheets formulas so please bear with me.

I have over a thousand invoices with varying number of rows across multiple spreadsheets, but each invoice being one tab within each sheet. I'm trying to figure out a way to spit out the word "End" in column A (for an automated process a third-party is building out) in the corresponding row of the last non-empty cell in Column F (i.e. last non-empty cell is Column F is F23, I want A23 to say "End"). Since the last non-empty cell in column F changes rows between each invoice, it's prevented me from using an Sheets formula, as I haven't figured out a way to only populate "End" in the same row as the actual last non-empty cell.

I've tried using the IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(... formula, but I'm not quite sure how to link this with only populating text relative to the last non-empty.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you used any array formulas?

Comment: Are all of the spreadsheets in the same folder  or do you have a list of all of the ids?

Comment: @Cooper  I have not yet tried an array formula yet - any input on how I could get the actual cell that the array outputs in to be correlated with the last cell of the specific column? The "End" statement is going to as a stop trigger for the script that will be reading these to-be exported sheets (exported into PDF's). 

All the spreadsheets are in the same parent folder with anywhere from 5-100 tabs per sheet, but there's only 20 total, so I have no problem copy and pasting the script from one sheet to the next once I get it down

Answer (score 1):

#### Set Column A to End

You need to provide the folder id in the second line and then hope that the script finishes in about 6 minutes.

This is not a Custom Script.  It must be run from a menu or script editor

```
function setColumnAToEnd() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderId");
  const files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
    ss.getSheets().forEach(sh => {
      let lr = getColumnHeight(6,sh,ss);
      sh.getRange(lr,1).setValue("End");
    })
  }
}

function getColumnHeight(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()){ rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
}
```

Comment: once again you leave me scratching my head and realizing how little I know.... I don't get how those first 3 lines are handling potential missing parameters. I would have done `if ss == undefined`. I'm especially confused with the `col` line. Shouldn't an OR `||` return `true` or `false` -- yet you have it returning an integer. And to make me more confused... I don't see how that code correctly notes to use the parameter `col instead of the `activeCell` column. Obviously it works as I tested, but I'll have to brush up on exactly how that works. Thanks for keeping the knowledge coming.

Comment: Okay I get it now as I did some more tinkering. Those or statements return the FIRST true result going left to right. So a falsey would get skipped. Clever and takes less code then my if statements. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably better ways to do this, but you can use this formula to find the last row in column F. `=MAX(FILTER(ROW(F:F),NOT(ISBLANK(F:F))))`

If you wanted to automate, I suppose you could do something weird like this... If you run this on your sheet, it should work.

**Updated to work on entire workbook.**

```
function fixAllSheets() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  allSheets.forEach(enterSomeEnd_)
}

function enterSomeEnd_(theSheet) {
  var someRandomCell = theSheet.getRange(theSheet.getMaxRows(), 1, 1, 1);
  someRandomCell.setFormula('=MAX(FILTER(ROW(F:F),NOT(ISBLANK(F:F))))');
  var theRow = someRandomCell.getValue();
  theSheet.getRange(theRow, 1).setValue("end");
  someRandomCell.clearContent();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm not quite sure how to use the formula as the reference cell in a conditional replacement formula, so I was trying to script the function you provided in, but I'm having trouble getting it to recognize as a separate function.

Comment: Still learning how to use stackoverflow, but I linked my current script i'd like to add this to below if you're able to see it @pgSystemTester

Comment: @MattOrzillo glad it works, but the proper stackOverflow protocol is to `accept` an answer, not to post answers which are really questions turned commentary, etc. (even if well-intentioned). If you'd be so kind as to accept either Cooper's or my answer, depending on which one you felt was most helpful, and then delete your below answer (unless admins do first), you'll be good. Welcome to SO...